# Html rich text to Microsoft Word

Tags: python, html, ms-word, docx, richtext

Right now i have this format:

"This is a bold **word**, *this is in italic*, this is regular"

Which translates to:

```
 <p>This is a bold <strong>word</strong>, <em>this is in italic</em>, this is regular.</p>
```

Is there any python library which turns the above code into `Microsoft Word` format? I couldn't find any, i found only `pandoc` and the subsequent `pypandoc` which read html but can only translate it into `.docx` format by saving a .docx file- and this isn't helpful.

I figured to ask a question here before i put work into writing a parser to do this.

Comment: How are you supposed to see the code in Microsoft Word Format if a .docx is not saved. A command-prompt cannot show bold or italic text

Comment: How and when do you want to convert it? On a link press? Manually? you can save the webpage and open it in word.

Comment: User inserts text using a `richtexteditor` such as `tinymce` or `ckeditor`, i get the input which is in the above example(html) and i need to convert it to `microsoft-word` format so that i can query the database at some point and compose a docx document from multiple db entries